# dojo load js script and then execute it

Tags: dojo

I am trying to load a template with xhr and then append it to the page in some div.
the problem is that the page loads the script but doesn't execute it.
the only solution I got is to add some flags in the page (say: "Splitter"), before the splitter, I put the js code, and after the splitter I add the html code, and when getting the template by ajax, I split it. here is an example:

the data I request by ajax is:

```
//js code:
work_types = <?php echo $work_types; ?>; //json data

<!-- Splitter -->

html code:
<div id="work_types_container"></div>
```

so the callback returns 'data' which I simply split and exeute like this:

```
data = data.split("<!-- Splitter -->");
dojo.query("#some_div").append(data[1]); //html part
eval(data[0]); //js part
```

Although this works for me, but it doesn't seem so professional!
is there another way in dojo to make it work?

Comment: have you tried using a closure? can you post the code up?

Comment: closure doesn't help because I need to define some variables in the php file because I can use php code there but not on js file.
the code u need is not necessary. think of an ajax request and it returns js code and html.
I use the code above with this returned data.

Comment: you're asking for alternative implementations, but you're not providing much to work with. There are always different ways of making it work, but without more information, you are essentially asking for theoretical responses.

Comment: I changed the question dear ermagana.

Comment: ok, thanks your question makes more sense... So eval is considered evil, because it opens you up to all sorts of vulnerabilities - you want to avoid using int. Is there a reason your js code can't be wrapped up in a single file?

Comment: it can't be wrapped because I have to define some veriables with php like you see.
I use these veriables in the js files but I define them in the php file.

Comment: could you provide an example, close to your actual data, of what these variables contain?

Comment: they contain json data, like this:
[{value: 0, label: 'a'}, {value: 0, label: 'b'}]

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Dojo, it might be worth to look at the `dojox/layout/ContentPane` module ([reference guide](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/layout/ContentPane.html)). It's quite similar to the `dijit/layout/ContentPane` variant but with one special extension, that it allows executing the JavaScript on that page (using `eval()`).

So if you don't want to do all that work by yourself, you could do something like:

```html
<div data-dojo-type="dojox/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="href: myXhrUrl, executeScripts: true"></div>
```

If you're concerned about it being a **DojoX** module (DojoX will disappear in Dojo 2.0), the module is labeled as **maintained**, so it has a higher chance of being integrated in `dijit` in later versions.

---

As an anwer to your `eval()` safety question (in comments). Well, it's allowed of course, else they wouldn't have such a function called `eval()`. But indeed, it's less secure, the reason for this is that the client in fact trusts the server and executes everything the server sends to the client.

Normally, there are no problems unless the server sends malicious content (this could be due to an issue on your server or man in the middle attacks) which will be executed and thus, causing an XSS vulnerability.

In the ideal world the server only sends data and the client interpretes this data and renders it by himself. In this design, the client only trusts data from the server, so no malicious logic can be executed (so there will be no XSS vulnerability).

It's unlikely that it will happen and the ideal world solution is not even possible in many cases since the initial page request (loading your webpage) is in fact a similar scenario where the client executes whatever the server sends.

Web application security is not about being 100% safe (it's impossible), but it's to try to create as less as possible open doors that can be used by hackers. It's up to you what you consider safe and to verify if the "ideal world" solution is possible in this specific scenario (it might not be, or it might take too much time compared to the other solution).

Comment: this works as you say.  
so I suppose that using eval() in this example is allowed.

Comment: I updated my answer with an answer about your `eval()` question. In this case, I don't think that using `eval()` will be a problem.